# Handle GetFolderAsync exceptions

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

I'm trying to follow the same structure from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795922/handling-windows-store-app-exceptions-from-getfileasync) to handle exceptions from async tasks. In this case `GetFolderAsync` from the `FutureAccessList`.

```
if (Windows::Storage::AccessCache::StorageApplicationPermissions::FutureAccessList->ContainsItem("PickedFolderToken")) {
  create_task(Windows::Storage::AccessCache::StorageApplicationPermissions::FutureAccessList->GetFolderAsync("PickedFolderToken")).then([this](StorageFolder^ folder)
  {
      //do some stuff
      auto query = folder->CreateFileQueryWithOptions(Q);
      return query->GetFilesAsync();
  }).then([this](IVectorView<StorageFile^>^ f)
  {
      // Process
  }).then([this](task<void> t)
  {
      try
      {
        t.get();
      }
      catch (Platform::Exception^ e)
      {
        // Handle error
        txt_currentPath->Text = "FOLDER NOT FOUND";
      }
  });
}
```

But running from VS2015 debug mode it still crashes with the following message

> WinRT information: The file or folder associated with the specified
>   token (PickedFolderToken) cannot be found. The file or folder may have
>   been moved or deleted.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

If I try to continue it just keeps throwing an exception. What am I missing?

**Update:**

Experimenting with `try` and `catch` in the following code still throws an exception...

```
try {
Windows::Storage::AccessCache::StorageApplicationPermissions::FutureAccessList->GetFolderAsync("PickedFolderToken");
}
catch (Exception^ e){
    OutputDebugString(L"ERROR");
}
```

**Update2:**

Typical Use Scenario:
- User opens the App. Selects a folder to open from within the app, e.g. C:\datasets\set1. The path is stored in FutureAccessList as "PickedFolderToken".
- The user finishes and exits the program.
- Later, they launch the program again and it automatically navigates to the folder stored in the FutureAccessList as "PickedFolderToken".

Exception case:
- The folder "C:\datasets\set1" has now been deleted or no longer available (maybe it pointed to an SD card E:\datasets\set1) outside of the app
- User launches the app and it crashes <- this is the exception I'm trying to handle

```
if (FutureAccessList->ContainsItem("PickedFolderToken"))
```

returns true as expected as the token string is still present in the `FutureAccessList`. The code at the top of the question doesn't catch the exception thrown by `GetFolderAsync`.

**Update3:**
I created a blank UWP project to test the code in a minimal setting and the code at the top of the post does actually work. There must be something else different in the project config.

Comment: The get() call returns the IVectorView you want.  Or throws the exception. So the second then() should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

> WinRT information: The file or folder associated with the specified token (PickedFolderToken) cannot be found. The file or folder may have been moved or deleted.
>   If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

The above error message is described very clearly. To solve this issue you could add folder to `FutureAccessList` with "PickedFolderToken". You could refer to the following code.

```
FolderPicker^ folderPicker = ref new FolderPicker();
folderPicker->SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId::Desktop;
folderPicker->FileTypeFilter->Append("*");

create_task(folderPicker->PickSingleFolderAsync()).then([this](StorageFolder^ folder)
{
    if (folder)
    {
        Windows::Storage::AccessCache::StorageApplicationPermissions::
            FutureAccessList->AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", folder);
    }
    else
    {

    }
});
```

**Update：**

> Typical Use Scenario:
>   - User opens the App. Selects a folder to open from within the app, e.g. >C:\datasets\set1. The path is stored in FutureAccessList as >"PickedFolderToken".
>   - The user finishes and exits the program.
>   - Later, they launch the program again and it automatically navigates to the >folder stored in the FutureAccessList as "PickedFolderToken".
>
> Exception case:
>   - The folder "C:\datasets\set1" has now been deleted or no longer available 
>   (maybe it pointed to an SD card E:\datasets\set1) outside of the app
>   - User launches the app and it crashes <- this is the exception I'm trying to >handle

To handle errors  in a task chain, you don't have to make every continuation task-based or enclose every operation that might throw within a try…catch block. Instead, you can add a task-based continuation at the end of the chain and handle all errors there. For more please refer to [Handling errors in a task chain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/asynchronous-programming-in-cpp-universal-windows-platform-apps#handling-errors-in-a-task-chain).

Comment: 'PickedFolderToken' has already been set when the application was last used. when the app is launched it opens the working folder that the user selected last session.  I'm using if(Windows::Storage::AccessCache::StorageApplicationPermissions::FutureAccessList->ContainsItem("PickedFolderToken")) to determine if this was set last time, it returns true as expected. I'm trying to handle the case where the previously selected working directory is no longer accessible.

Comment: Could you show more detail about your selected working directory?